# Enable optional english navigation

Tags: novo-recurso, status-recusado

### Inroduction

I am interested in a few tags which don't have too many users, and perhaps won't have any Portuguese power-users for a while. Therefore I considered browsing the Portuguese stack overflow, to track down questions that might otherwise get stuck, and refer to an English equivalent if it exists.

This would enable many people with limited content knowledge to answer the question properly. Or at least give people an idea of what they would need to get to a solution.

### The problem

It may be challenging for me and other users to navigate the site as not only the contents are in Portuguese, but also the navigation buttons. Thus I request something to assist the non Portuguese people who do want to contribute to the succes of the site.

### The request

Can we give people the choice to have the Portuguese SO site in English, with only the content in Portuguese?

Answer (score 3):

We've discussed this, but I don't think it'll happen for the foreseeable future.

Also, while pointing to equivalent questions in English could be useful in some cases, it's likely that most people browsing SOPT won't be able to understand it. A link to other content in English would be useful *in addition* to a Portuguese answer, but by itself it's probably of little value.